# How to prove inequalities in geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Outline:

[image: outline]

In a triangle $\triangle ABC$ let $\overline{AB}$ be the longest of the three sides. Let $G$ be the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ and $M$ the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. Furthermore, let a point $D$ outside the triangle be given. The following inequalities now apply:

1. The distance from $D$ to the vertices of the triangle is less than $1$.
2. The side $\overline{AB}$ is bigger than $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ but less than $\sqrt 2$.
3. The median $\overline{CM}$ is bigger than $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.

Prove: $\overline{DG}<\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.

I experimented a bit with Geogebra and found out by measuring side lengths that the statement holds. I can't find much on the internet about these kinds of problems with geometric inequalities. Therefore, I would be interested in what possibilities there are to approach such problems. I have tried to make progress with the triangle inequality and Ptolomew's inequality, but have not yet reached my goal, because the estimates were always too inaccurate.
Edit: The best possible bound to prove is $DG<\frac{\sqrt 7}{3}$.

Comment: To clarify, for point 1, do you mean that the 3 distances $DA$, $DB$ and $DC$ are all less than $1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by less than $1$, less than $\sqrt2$, etc.?

Comment: A triangle has many "centers": Circumcenter, incenter, barycenter (median center), orthocenter,... What do you mean by geometric center?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet , apperantly, it is [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid).

Comment: @ACB There is no harm to say for example "less than $1$". There is an implicit choice made of a certain unit length, that's all.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I don't get it. What is the unit length here?

Comment: @ACB Another way to write down the problem would be to multiply all the numbers by constant $a$ where $a$ takes into account the dimensionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting a math contest practice problem vibe, so I will give you a couple of hints. Let me know if you want more details.

1. Prove $$DA^2+DB^2+DC^2 = 3DG^2 + GA^2+GB^2+GC^2.$$
2. Prove $$CM^2 = \dfrac{9}{4}GC^2 = \dfrac{2(AC^2+CB^2)-AB^2}{4}$$
3. Prove $$GA^2+GB^2+GC^2 = \dfrac{AB^2+BC^2+  CA^2}{3}$$
   but this is a very well-known identity.

Then, using the bounds specific to your problem, you should be able to get an upper bound on $DG.$

Comment: Proving the first identity is not very difficult, the third follows directly from the first and the second is simply the standard formula for the median in a triangle. But I don't really see how to get to the upper bound I'm looking for. By substituting one comes to $DG^2=\frac{DA^2+DB^2+DC^2}{3}-\frac{\frac{1}{6}(4\cdot CM^2+3\cdot AB^2)}{3}$. If you use the given inequalities, you get an upper bound, but it is not precise enough ($DG \leq \frac{\sqrt{29}}{6}$).

Comment: I am getting $DG < \dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{3}$ once the given bounds are applied. Besides, the lower bound $c > \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$ is actually implied by the other two bounds given and one can construct a triangle satisfying those two bounds for any given value of $AB.$ This means that either $DA^2+DB^2+DC^2 < 3$ is too crude or there is a counterexample to this problem.

Comment: $DG<\frac{\sqrt 7 }{3}$ should be the best bound, I just tried it again with Geogebra. Since it's not a competition task or anything like that, but I came across the problem myself, it's not particularly surprising. Hopefully I and all those who visited this post were able to learn something from it anyway. Thank you very much for your help!